# Subsection within enumerate

Tags: sectioning, errors, lists, enumerate

Why does the following produce an error,

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \subsection{Error}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

But the following compile just fine:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item \subsection{Fine}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Test}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\item \subsection{Fine}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The ones that don't give an error just get accidentally lucky, using a higher level sectioning command inside a lower level list can't ever be the right markup, even when it works.

Comment: What would be the reason for starting a subsection as an item in an enumerated list?

Comment: It's not an exact subsection I want, but the item in the enumerate does need to be divided into multiple parts for clarity. If subsection is not what I want, I guess I'll declare a new macro which looks similar?

Answer (score 5):

Unlike in other languages most of the macros in (La)TeX are not context sensitive (this really holds for the vast majority -- there are exeptions though). And `\subsection` is really "just" a plain sectioning command and meant to create headings. You should only use it for that purpose. The definition in the standard classes looks like

```
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
```

As you see there is an auxiliary macro `\@startsection` (I wont paste its definition here, you can see it in `latex.ltx`) as the process of sectioning can be abstracted. What it basically does is to set a few dimensions, taking care that the heading wont be the last line on a page and printing the actual heading. And that's its (fixed) meaning.

In your example you are clearly *not* marking the beginn of a new subsection inside that list -- except you have an extremely eccentric design idea. Most likely you want to split an entry into several parts or subitmes (or "subsections" so to speak). In that case you can simply start a new list inside the other one. LaTeX supports nesting of list environments:

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item item
  \begin{enumerate}
    \item subitem 1
    \item subitem 2
    \item ...
  \end{enumerate}
  \item another item
  \item ...
\end{enumerate}
```

If you want the nested `enumerate` labels to look more like the subsections counter you could the following.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\section{section}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item item
  \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi.\arabic*.]
    \item part 1
    \item part 2
    \item ...
  \end{enumerate}
  \item another item
  \item ...
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: example_rendered]